# Illegal Monitor State Exception for this producer consumer?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency

Was trying to practice producer and consumer using a simple counter in java.
Not sure why I am getting a Illegal Monitor State exception on this piece of code.

I have counter rest and counter consume methods which run in their own thread.
The counter itself is a static int volatile field .
The counter class also gives you a lock to

If I change the wait naotify to the following:

```
Counter.lock.notify();
Counter.lock.wait();
```

The code works. Dosen't wait() and notify() automatically takes the reference of the lock synchronize is on?

Producer Class

```
package multithreading;


public class CounterProducer implements Runnable {


public void run() {

    try {   incrCounter();   } catch (InterruptedException e) {            e.printStackTrace();        }
}

public void incrCounter() throws InterruptedException {


    while (true) {
        synchronized (Counter.lock) {
            if (Counter.counter < 1) {
                System.out.println("Counter Reset");
                Counter.counter = 10;
                notify();
                wait();
            }


        }
    }


}
```

}

Consumer Class

```
package multithreading;


public class CounterConsumer implements Runnable {


    public void run() {

        try {   consumeCounter();   } catch (InterruptedException e) {            e.printStackTrace();        }
    }

    public void consumeCounter() throws InterruptedException {


        while (true) {
            synchronized (Counter.lock) {
                if (Counter.counter > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Consumed");
                    Counter.counter--;
                    notify();
                    wait();
                }


            }
        }


    }

}

The Counter

public class Counter {

    public static volatile int counter;

    public static final Object lock = new Object();

}
```

The Counter

```
public class CounterRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread con = new Thread(new CounterConsumer());
        Thread prod = new Thread(new CounterProducer());

        con.start();
        prod.start();

    }


}
```

The Runner

```
public class CounterRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread con = new Thread(new CounterConsumer());
        Thread prod = new Thread(new CounterProducer());

        con.start();
        prod.start();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I change the wait naotify to the following, the code works:
>
> ```
> Counter.lock.notify();
> Counter.lock.wait();
> ```

Every Java method is either a static method of some class or an instance method of some object.  If you see a method call that does not contain an explicit class name or object reference, then it is an implicit call to a method belonging to the `this` object.

That is to say, `notify()` means the same thing as `this.notify()`, and `wait()` means `this.wait()`.

`this`, refers to the `CounterProducer` instance when it appears in your `CounterProducer.incrCounter()` method, and it refers to the `CounterConsumer` instance when it appears in your `CounterConsumer.consumeCounter()` method.